# Как сделать конвейер в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Делаю игру на телефон по типу satisfactory, factorio, dyson sphere program, игра у меня в 3д с видом сверху, и у меня никак не получается сделать конвейеры без физики(физика работает не очень, и лагает на телефоне), и нигде не могу найти как это сделать, мне нужно чтобы руда ездила по сплайну(или другой метод если знаете) и **останавливалась** если в конце сплайна есть другая руда, чтобы они не накладывались друг на друга, вроде можно как-то от прогрессии одного объекта считать другой, но я даже не представляю как это, работаю в юнити недавно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Физика тут точно ни к чему, это как забивание шурупов микроскопом. Думайте в сторону "Пятнашек".